# Find the ID after compiling

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

When you assign something an ID in asp.net such as:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="mylabel" Text="some text"></asp:Label>
```

The code behind ID you use to reference that object is mylabel.

However after the site has compiled and is running the ID in the HTML changes to something a bit more abscure

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="ct100_blahblah_what_mylabel" Text="some text"></asp:Label>
```

And I cannot (don't know how) to reliably predict what it will be to select it with javascript.

Is there a way to ask the server what the ID for that label is at any given moment?

What are some keywords could use to find out more about this phenomenon?

Comment: This is damn annoying and I've been subjected to this myself. As the answers point out, you'll need to use ClientID for that. What I did was to use <%=control.ClientID%> blocks whenever I needed to get a specific controls element id. It is sadly very cumbersome, and hardly a good solution but may be the only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `ClientID` property. This contains the generated id of the control at runtime. You could emit some JavaScript in the code behind that sets the client id of your control to a JavaScript variable so you can reference it.

**EDIT: added example**

The following will find the label using the ClientID and then update its text.

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="mylabel" Text="some text"></asp:Label>

        <script language="javascript">
            var mylabelID = "<%= mylabel.ClientID %>";
            var label = document.getElementById(mylabelID);
            label.innerHTML += " changed";
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could I have an example please?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for the [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property.

> The `ClientID` value is often used to
>   programmatically access the HTML
>   element rendered for a control in
>   client-side script.

Your other option is to wrap your control in an HTML element like this:

```
<span id="foo">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="mylabel" Text="some text"></asp:Label>
</span>
```

Since this outer element does not have the `runat="server"` attribute, its id will not be changed on render.  This would mean that your JavaScript function would have to to be changed to pull an inner element from the span `foo` or if you are using a JavaScript framework like jQuery you could pull the label back like this:

```
$("span#foo span");
```

Comment: Could I have an example please?